# Is redundant code acceptable if it improves readability?

Tags: java, coding-style

I have the following code to check if a game unit is a player or an enemy.  These are the only two categories.  I could delete the isEnemy method and run all checks for enemy as if(!isPlayer), but I personally feel that if(isEnemy) makes the intent of the code clearer.  Are there any established coding styles that have anything to say about this kind of situation?

```
public boolean isPlayer(Unit unit) {
    return unit == player;
}

public boolean isEnemy(Unit unit) {
    for (Unit e : enemies) {
        if (unit.equals(e))
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: IMHO If you write code with a purpose, anything you add which doesn't need to be there is confusing.  You can waste more time trying to find the purpose of something which has no purpose than something which obviously has one.  In your example, it not clear how one method can be replaced with the other.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think having both methods is acceptable.  If isEnemy() == !isPlayer() I would consider implementing isEnemy() as:

```
public boolean isEnemy(Unit unit) {
  return !isPlayer(unit);
}
```

This way you gain the readability of having two specific methods but not necessarily repeating yourself as if you can adjust isPlayer() and affect both methods.

Answer (score 6):

For your case, you have only two possible states - they're either an enemy, or they're a player.  If they're a player, they are not an enemy.  The cleanest way to express that would be `!isPlayer`.

If you had other possible states,then you may want to look into some sort of enumeration on the other states.

As a general rule of thumb:  [Don't Repeat Yourself](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself).  If one part of your code changes that you've duplicated (perhaps to fix a bug), you then have to change every occurrence of that bug.  It can turn into a maintenance nightmare.

Answer (score 3):

Personally, I would implement `isEnemy()` as `!isPlayer()` but have the an `assert` that runs the loop to make sure it really is an enemy.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, that's absolutely acceptable. Especially in big project, readability is very import. Also consider that, if you add the third role in future, then you wouldn't be able to use if (!isPlayer).

Answer (score 1):

By looking at your code you are identifying the enemy if it is present in the collection 'enemies'. So for you an enemy is not essentially someone who is not a player. If you want to enforce this semantic then I don't think you should get away with isEnemy() method.

Another reason you may need isEnemy() method is if you see a possibility of another type say Ally. Having isEnemy() method will make that addition simpler and cleaner.

But if above 2 conditions are not valid then get rid of it. As they say YAGNI :)